# Pipe Character - Alternative solutions

Tags: linux, keyboard

I am currently using bash in linux, however I cannot seem to create the | character.
It is on the keyboard but when trying to create it it brings up the ~ character.

Is there any alternative ways to achieve this.

I am stuck until I can get past this.

Comment: Check your keyboard settings as to which region/language it is configured for.

Comment: @jjk_charles Are you able to help me do that? All I have is bash and a USB keyboard.

Comment: which distro are you using?

Comment: @jjk_charles Trying to use Gentoo

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gnome or KDE, goto System Settings->Input devices or Settings->Region & Languages->Input Sources and add/remove the appropriate keyboard layout.

If you want to change it from terminal, use the below command:

```
setxkbmap us
```

where `us` is the identifier for one of the keyboard layouts. Check this [link](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout_switching) which lists several other approaches to achieve the same.

Note: `setxkbmap -query` will help you check what is the current keyboard layout being used, if at all you want to revert back to current settings at a later point of time!

Comment: thanks, setxkbmap returns command not found, however I followed the link and was able to locate */etc/conf.d/keymaps*, *keymap="us"* is already set, with *extended_keymaps="backspace keypad euro2"* set. My keyboard is a US keyboard, I have tried changing us to uk but when pressing the "|" key button it still outputs "~" character.